# Get orientation in degrees

Tags: android, android-sensors

I am trying to create a simple compass app (for learning purposes) and I am using the rotation matrix using the magnetic sensor and accelerometer. This is my code:

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
        geomagnetic[0] = event.values[0];
        geomagnetic[1] = event.values[1];
        geomagnetic[2] = event.values[2];
        havemag = true;
    }
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        gravity[0] = event.values[0];
        gravity[1] = event.values[1];
        gravity[2] = event.values[2];
        haveacc = true;
    }

    if (haveacc && havemag) {
        if (SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(Rm, I, gravity, geomagnetic)) {
            float[] result = new float[3];
            SensorManager.getOrientation(Rm, result);

            azimuth = result[0];
            pitch = result[1];
            roll = result[2];
        }
    }
}
```

When I look at these values while moving my phone though (outputing using `Log.d`), I get incorrect values. I use this code to make degrees out of them:

```
int deg = (int)(azimuth * (float)57.295);
```

But this value never reaches zero (which is supposed to be on the exact opposite side of 180/-180). Instead, the opposite of where 180/-180 is, I get -85 (approx).

Comment: I tried another app from the Plat Store and it looks like the compass on my phone (Galaxy Nexus) is not very good.

Comment: Or perhaps you are sitting next to a large magnet. :-)

Comment: For having often this issue with geolocation. An advice I can give you : Computers are full of magnets : try to use compass features of your phone away from computers.

Comment: @gahfy thanks, I have been walking around a little away from the computer. Perhaps it will work better outside. I have also found another phone that seems to have better results.

Comment: Depending on your device, you may also be able to get bearing from GPS.

Answer (score 6):

You should use the proper JavaMath function to convert your radian angle to degree. Furthermore converting the angle (in degree) to a [0 - 360] degree interval is very useful.

```
// angle in degree [-180 - 0 - 180] degree
azimuth = Math.toDegrees( result[0] )

// angle in degree [0 - 360] degree
azimuth = ( Math.toDegrees( result[0] ) + 360 ) % 360;
```